# desmos graphing calclulator and misleading results

Tags: graphing-functions

Go ahead and load the desmos calculator:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Now graph $x^x$

You should see something like this. An apparent continuation of the curve is shown.

[image: ghost]

Upon zooming in, it vanishes! What is causing Desmos to be haunted by ghosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root issue is that the notation $x^x$ does not represent a well-defined real-valued function when $x\leq 0$.

Probably the most sensible continuation to negative numbers is via restriction of the complex function $F(x) = \exp(x \log x)$ to the real line. Of course $\log(x)$ is multi-valued so you could take e.g. the principal value. But this produces non-real results for some rational values of $x$ where one might "expect" a real result, i.e. $F(-1/3)$ is complex and does not equal $-\sqrt[3]{3}.$

What Desmos seems to be doing instead is extending $x^x$ to a real-valued function on the negative rationals with odd denominator (and leaving $f$ undefined at other negative $x$). This explains the sign alternation as well as why the function disappears when you zoom in: if Desmos happens to only sample $f$ at negative points that aren't rational with odd denominator, it won't draw anything because all sampled values are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bnp1-Xd-Eo4) which gives an explanation. The reason there is that for negative  $x$ such that $x \geq -1$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ is even $x^x$ is imaginary.